# Gunicorn cannot write logfile if permissions are lower than 666

Tags: linux, gunicorn

I spent a long time going crazy trying to solve why gunicorn was giving me 502 errors when I was trying to enable logging and I finally found it was the permissions of the logfiles.

Gunicorn is requiring me to have no lower than 666 permissions, otherwise it gives me 502's. Is there some reason why Gunicorn is set up like this? I never read anything about it in the docs and it seems weird...

How can I change this? Should I bother changing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Permission 666 = rw rw rw` There is no execute flag as you see, any web server needs permission to execute files in directories.

Update : Actually any programs needs execute flag for any execution process in working directory.

Comment: so what are you saying? It is working with 666 and no execute flag, did you understand my question?

Comment: Upps sorry I did understand you wrong, I did missed the part of logging. OK, then you are need permissions like 664 or 644. For '644' Gunicorn have to work under your tty user. If you cannot achieve this, change to '664' and add your Gunicorn user to a group  ex: X and make log directory's group as X. You can also achieve this purpose with ACL but I have no detailed information you may check http://bencane.com/2012/05/27/acl-using-access-control-lists-on-linux/

Comment: ahh yes I just had to chown to the user that gunicorn runs under, thanks